# Split associative array by key

Tags: php

I have array like this:

```
private $schedule = [
    "13:00" => true,
    "13:30" => false,
    "14:00" => true,
    "14:30" => true,
    "15:00" => true,
    "15:30" => true,
    "16:00" => true,
]
```

For example current time is "14:00".

I want is to split this array into two arrays:

before "14:00"

```
 private $schedule1 = [
    "13:00" => true,
    "13:30" => false,
    "14:00" => true
]
```

after "14:00"

```
private $schedule2 = [
   "14:30" => true,
   "15:00" => true,
   "15:30" => true,
   "16:00" => true,
]
```

Is there way to do this by key ("14:00")?

Comment: `$before1400 = array_filter($schedule, function($key) { return $key <= '14:00'; }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY); $after1400 = array_filter($schedule, function($key) { return $key > '14:00'; }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);`

Comment: @MarkBaker  is came up with the perfect solution. Post it as an answer

Comment: possible in php version > 5.6.0

Comment: Pasha you have many answers below. check them and try to mark+up-vote one which is correct for you.You can up-vote others too if they are useful too.Thanks

Comment: @MarkBaker, thanks, works good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$before1400 = array_filter($schedule, function($key) { 
    return $key <= '14:00'; }, 
ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY); 

$after1400 = array_filter($schedule, function($key) { 
    return $key > '14:00'; }, 
ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$split = array_search('14:00', $schedule);

print_r(array_slice($data, 0, $split))   // first part
print_r(array_slice($data, $split + 1)); // second part
?>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 3):

Simple `foreach()` iteration with a flag could attain this:-

```
$curr = '14:00';
$schedule1 = $schedule2 = array();
//maintain a flag which would track when the required time key is reached
$timeReached = FALSE;

foreach ($schedule as $key => $val) {
  if (!$timeReached) {
    $schedule1[$key] = $val;
  }
  else {
    $schedule2[$key] = $val;
  }
  //set the flag when the key is reached.
  if ($key == $curr) {
    $timeReached = TRUE;
  }
}

print_r($schedule1);
print_r($schedule2); // would be the required array.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `foreach`. Result: https://eval.in/714864

```
<?php

$schedule = [
    "13:00" => true,
    "13:30" => false,
    "14:00" => true,
    "14:30" => true,
    "15:00" => true,
    "15:30" => true,
    "16:00" => true,
];


$schedule1 = [];
$schedule2 = [];

$current_time = "14:00"; //date("H:i");

echo 'Current Time: '. $current_time;

echo '<br />';


foreach($schedule as $key => $val){
    if($key<=$current_time){
        $schedule1[$key] = $val;
    }else{
        $schedule2[$key] = $val;
    }
}

print_r($schedule);

echo '<br />';

print_r($schedule1);

echo '<br />';

print_r($schedule2);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple function using a `foreach` loop to check the keys could solve it. You can try something like:

```
  $schedule = [
    "13:00" => true,
    "13:30" => false,
    "14:00" => true,
    "14:30" => true,
    "15:00" => true,
    "15:30" => true,
    "16:00" => true,
]

function array_split($array, $delimiter) {
  $first_half = [];
  $second_half = [];

  foreach (array_keys($array) as $key) {
      if ($key < $delimiter) {
        $first_half[$key] = $array[$key];
      }
      else {
        $second_half[$key] = $array[$key];
      }
  } 

  return [$first_half, $second_half];
}

list($first_half, $second_half) = array_split($schedule, '14:00');
```

or you could do away with just a couple of calls to [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-filter.php):

```
$first_half = array_filter($schedule, function($key) { return $key <= '14:00'; }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
$second_half = array_filter($schedule, function($key) { return $key  '14:00'; }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try other way as:-

```
$schedule1 = [];
$schedule2 = [];
$flag      = false;
foreach ($schedule as $k => $v) {
    if ($k == date("H:i")) {
        $schedule1[] = $v;
        $flag        = true;
    }
    if ($flag) {
        $schedule2[] = $v;
    } else {
        $schedule1[] = $v;
    }
}
```

This code will work for even random keys. Give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

The idea in the answer from suman das is correct, however the code contains some errors. This code sample works:

```
<?php

$schedule = [
    '13:00' => true,
    '13:30' => false,
    '14:00' => true,
    '14:30' => true,
    '15:00' => true,
    '15:30' => true,
    '16:00' => true,
];

$split = array_search('14:00', array_keys($schedule), true);

$lessThan = array_slice($schedule, 0, $split);
$lessThanOrEqual= array_slice($schedule, 0, $split + 1);

$greaterThenOrEqual = array_slice($schedule, $split);
$greaterThen = array_slice($schedule, $split + 1);
```